# How to compile a single file with maven?

Tags: java, vim, maven-2

I set up a working maven project with `mvn archetype:create ...`
I can compile all the sources with `mvn compile` but I want to be able to compile also a single file at time.

There is a way to ask maven to compile an arbitrary single .java file?

Thanks

**Updates 1:**

I would specify the single file on the command line. I would choose the file at the moment of the command launch. I wouldn't modify the pom.xml.

**Update 2:**

Why I asked this? Because I would use `autotest-java` with the Vim editor.

`autotest-java` is an hack/extension of ZenTest (which is a Ruby application that automatically launch unit tests on every save of a Ruby file).

`autotest-java` requires a maven project structure and requires that your editor/IDE perform "compile on save". In fact it doesn't recognize when a .java file is modified but instead it monitors for .class files for modifications.

I succesfully used autotest-java with Netbeans (which support "compile on save") but I would use it with Vim.

Comment: Why? What advantage would compiling only a single file have?

Comment: @Joachim: I would enable "compile on save" on Vim in order to use vim with autotest-java.

Comment: This is actually a required feature with a build system to be able to compile just a single file. Even more so in C++

Comment: @JoachimSauer compiling a single file on changes might be a lot faster than re-compiling everything...500ms vs 500 seconds..

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge, this is not possible on the the command line. And it is worth noting that the (optional) parameters [`excludes`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#excludes) and [`includes`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#includes) that you can define to configure the Compiler Plugin in the `pom.xml` are deprecated as shown below:

```
$ mvn help:describe -Dcmd=compiler:compile -Ddetail
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'help'.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building sandbox
[INFO]    task-segment: [help:describe] (aggregator-style)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [help:describe {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] 'compiler:compile' is a plugin goal (aka mojo).
Mojo: 'compiler:compile'
compiler:compile
  Description: Compiles application sources
  Deprecated. No reason given
  Implementation: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo
  Language: java
  Bound to phase: compile

  Available parameters:

    ...

    excludes
      A list of exclusion filters for the compiler.
      Deprecated. No reason given

    ...

    includes
      A list of inclusion filters for the compiler.
      Deprecated. No reason given

    ...
```

So there is actually no real way to do what you want on the long term.

But this leads to one question. Since Maven uses incremental compilation i.e. it compiles  only classes that changed on disk since the last build, why would you need to compile only one class? What is your use case?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My use case is use autotest-java with vim.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to [configure the compiler plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html) to **exclude** the other files or to **include** just that one.

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <!-- put your configurations here -->
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would specify the single file on the command line. I would choose the file at the moment of the command launch. I wouldn't modify the pom.xml.

Comment: In the plugin's configuration add a variable instead of a file path.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain how?